# Minecraft Modding - with Fabric

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I have just started minecraft modding and I am a bit unsure of how to do something. I am trying to add Platinum into the Fabric modded minecraft game and that all worked but I am unsure how to make my platinum ore generate randomly like other ones. I have looked at lots of videos but none I saw have been very helpful at all.

My question at the end is:

***How do I randomly generate my platinum ore at y = 12 - 15 without having to place it by hand?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a ConfiguredFeature. Make sure to register your ConfiguredFeature at onInitialize. Feel free to change the values to suit your mod.

```
public class ExampleMod implements ModInitializer {
  private static ConfiguredFeature<?, ?> ORE_WOOL_OVERWORLD = Feature.ORE
    .configure(new OreFeatureConfig(
      OreFeatureConfig.Rules.BASE_STONE_OVERWORLD,
      Blocks.WHITE_WOOL.getDefaultState(),
      9)) // vein size
    .decorate(Decorator.RANGE.configure(new RangeDecoratorConfig(
    UniformHeightProvider.create(
    YOffset.fixed(0), 
    YOffset.fixed(64)))))
    .spreadHorizontally()
    .repeat(20); // number of veins per chunk
 
  @Override
  public void onInitialize() {
    RegistryKey<ConfiguredFeature<?, ?>> oreWoolOverworld = RegistryKey.of(Registry.CONFIGURED_FEATURE_WORLDGEN,
        new Identifier("tutorial", "ore_wool_overworld"));
    Registry.register(BuiltinRegistries.CONFIGURED_FEATURE, oreWoolOverworld.getValue(), ORE_WOOL_OVERWORLD);
    BiomeModifications.addFeature(BiomeSelectors.foundInOverworld(), GenerationStep.Feature.UNDERGROUND_ORES, oreWoolOverworld);
  }
}
```

(Took from https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:ores )